# Are the prime ideals of tensor product of fields maximal ideals?

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

The problem comes from a statement in Algebraic Geometry. Let $k$ be a field and $E/k$, $F/k$ are field extensions. Then the statement says there is an bijection between

$$
\operatorname{Spec}(E \otimes_k F)
$$
and the set of classes of composite fields of $E$ and $F$.

I know that if $L$ is the composite field of $E$ and $F$. Then there is a natural homomorphism $E \otimes_k F \longrightarrow L$ (Note this does not need to be surjective). The kernel is always a prime ideal. (See Bourbaki's Albgera, V, 2.4)

From my perspective, this is far away from $\operatorname{Spec}(E \otimes_k F)$. Are the prime ideals of tensor product of fields maximal ideals?

Comment: Yes, because every element in $E\otimes_k F$ is semi-simple over $k$, so $E\otimes_k F$ is a direct sum of field extensions of $k$.

Comment: @ChadK, can you give details? I do not know what an element being semi-simple means. I know semi-simple rings and modules. $E \otimes_k F$ is a $k$-vector space. But I do not see that it is a direct sum of fields.

Comment: $x\in E\otimes_k F$ semi-simple means the minimal polynomial of $x$ over $k$ splits into distinct irreducible factors.  BTW, I'm assuming $E,F$ are *finite* field extensions of $k$.  You didn't actually say that.

Comment: I do not assume finite extension of separable extension.

Comment: I was mistaken, $E\otimes_k F$ can have non-zero nilpotent elements.  At any rate, this property you're seeking is called having Krull dimension zero, and the result on this is in [The Dimension of the Tensor Product of Two Field Extensions](https://academic.oup.com/blms/article-abstract/9/1/42/293400) by Rodney Y. Sharp.

Comment: Thank @ChadK. I see that the statement in my question should be the case where $trdeg E/k$ = 0 = $trdeg F/k$.

Answer (score 0):

**Lemma 1.** For a commutative ring $A$, $\dim A$ = $\dim (A/rad(A))$.

**Lemma 2. [Chapter 5, GTM 256]** $\dim k[X_1,\dots, X_n] = n$.

**Lemma 3.** Assume there are $k$-algebras $A,B$ and $A$ is a field. $A/A'$ is an algebraic extension. Then $\dim A' \otimes_k B = \dim A \otimes_k B$.

**Proof:** Using Zorn's Lemma, we can reduce to the case where $A = A'[u]$, where $u$ is algebraic over $A'$.
$$
A \otimes_k B = A \otimes_{A'} (A' \otimes_k B)
$$
Essentially, $A \cong A'[X]/(m(X))$, where $m(X)$ is an irreducible polynomial of $A'[X]$. So
$$
A \otimes_k B = (A' \otimes_k B)[X]/((A' \otimes_k B)m(X))
$$
Obviously, $\dim A' \otimes_k B \leq \dim (A' \otimes_k B)[X]/((A' \otimes_k B)m(X))$.

To prove the converse inequality, note that the constant term of $m(X)$ is not zero. So $X \in (A' \otimes_k B)[X]/((A' \otimes_k B)m(X))$ is invertible. Every prime ideal in $(A' \otimes_k B)[X]/((A' \otimes_k B)m(X))$ can be contracted to a prime ideal in $A' \otimes_k B$. If prime ideals $P_1 \subset P_2$ of $(A' \otimes_k B)[X]/((A' \otimes_k B)m(X))$ are not equal, then $P_1 \cap (A' \otimes_k B ) \subset P_2 \cap (A' \otimes_k B)$ is a strict inclusion. Otherwise, if $P_1 \cap  (A' \otimes_k B ) = P_2 \cap  (A' \otimes_k B )$, then for $f_2(X) \in P_2 \backslash P_1$, $\exists f_1(X) \in P_1(X)$ with the same constant term. Then $f_2(X) - f_1(X) \not= 0$ is invertible, contrdicting the fact $P_2$ is a prime ideal.

Therefore, $\dim A' \otimes_k B = \dim A \otimes_k B$.

Finally, I prove the main theorem.

**Theorem.** $\dim E\otimes_k F = \min(\operatorname{trdeg} E/k, \operatorname{trdeg} F/k)$.

**Proof:** This follows from the three lemmas above.